# Redemption unable to extract message

Tags: outlook-redemption

we are facing one issue in C#.net application using redeption to extract attachment from PST, in this issue when we try to get rdomail object  for particular message,  than application is stuck.

we able to extract same message manually..but when we extract for that whole pst using code it stuck on that message.

is there any workaround in code to resolve this issue?
Please note PST file has large size(63 GB)

Thanks

Comment: You should edit your question to include the relevant parts of your existing code.

Comment: What code exactly do you use? What line of code causes a delay or freeze? Do you get any exception in the code?

Comment: Please post the relevant snippet of your code and indicate which line hangs. Send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) dom and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, i tried with debug version and looking furture at detail , i found there was issue while fetching loose attachment metadata  and application stuck on that , so i require to look in that case.  thanks for guiding.